# add Row to an array

Tags: c++

I need to add values to an array, for example:

```
int anArray[4][5]
     ={{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, }, // row 0
     { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, }, // row 1
     { 11, 12, 13, 14, 150 } // row 2
     };

anArray+= (15,17,71,93,18);//mistake
```

how to solve it and is possible to use ++ operator like c# :

```
++anArray[15,17,71,93,18];
```

Comment: its a static array. Unless you're fine with the answer "edit the code, save it with the new row added, and recompile" you better consider dynamic allocation.

Comment: You may need a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: yes, like @R.MartinhoFernandes said, you should consider learning to use std::vector<> from the c++ standard library.

Comment: Your example won't compile as you only assign 3 rows and say there are 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is not an object but a collection of consecutive position in memory containing `int`. You cannot dynamically grow it as [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) does. Consider using std::vector, pre-allocate memory enough and then copy new values using [memcopy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) or dynamically allocate and release (using `new` and `delete`) a new buffer when new size is known.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support addition of rows into static arrays.In case you need dynamically growing array, vector is your guy for the job.
If you don't want to use vectors then initialize the array with the required number of rows and recompile your program.